# Find the dimension of the intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

If $u = \{f \in P_{4} | f(3) = 0 \}$

$w = \{g \in P_{4} | g(2) = 0 \}$

Then $u \cap w  = \{h \in P_{4} | h(3) = 0,  h(2) = 0 \}$

How can we find the dimension of each of these subspaces? Dimension theorem states that the dimension of $u$ and $w$ should be (4+1), however when checking the answer, the question says the correct dimension should be 4 for both $u$ and $w$. Additionally it says  $u \cap w$ should have a dimension of 5. Bit confused to why this is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I dont get it. I assume that $P_4$ is the vector space of polynomials over $\mathbb R$ with degree less or equal than 4. Then $P_4$ should be a 5-dimensional vector space, $U$ and $V$ should be 4-dimensional and the dimension of $U \cap V$ should be bounded by 4, or did I got something wrong?

Comment: You are correct, but I do not understand why they have the dimensions you have listed

Comment: I dont know how much linear algebra you have learnt so far, so I dont really know how to answer it in a way suitable to you. Do you know of the dimension of a vector space and calculations you can do with it? Do you know that you can write a polynomial as a product of a linear factor and a polynomial, in the case that it has a zero?

Comment: I've taken 2 linear algebra classes. I know what you're referring to. Why don't you just answer the question regularly and if I have any questions maybe you could clarify.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, $U$ is given by polynomials of the form $(a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0)(x-3)$, so $\{x^i(x-3)\mid i=0..4\}$ should be a basis, ie. $U$ has dimension 4. Similarly for $V$. $U \cap V$ is a subspace of both $U$ and $V$, so by the dimension axiom cannot possibly be have dimension larger than the minimum of both dimensions, i.e. has to be $\leq 4$. In fact, just using the same trick as before, elements in $U \cap V$ should have the form $(c_2x^2 + c_1x + c_0)(x-2)(x-3)$, so $U \cap V$ should have dimension 3.

Comment: The issue is, on the website where the answers were submitted, $U \cap V$ had dimension 5, not 3.

Comment: You know, sometimes typos happen. Did you try to contact and ask the person responsible for it? It seems wrong to me. If the underlying ring of your polynomials is not a field however, the $P_4$ thingy is not a vector space but a module and strange things can happen there. So please check that too...

Comment: I did not try actually, I am asking this for a friend (they are in the course, I am not). But I appreciate you going over this with me

Comment: You are welcome. Sadly I cant help you, as long as no new information comes up. I hope my explanation of what I think the dimensions should be was clear enough though. Otherwise feel free to ask...

Comment: Yeah next time I see them I'll bring up this problem again, so you'll maybe hear back from me in a week!